# Hide a folder in azure webapi

Tags: path, hide, public

I published my webapi in azure. In my webapi there is a section where i can upload some files. Authentication and authorization are required. After authentication/authorization i can store a file in this path: https://www.myapi.com/attachments/. I found that everyone can access to my path without authorization and authentication. How can i set that nobody will be able to access to it? Some settings in Azure ? Have to work with routing path? I searched a lot but didn't find a solution. Can you help me?
Regards
C

Tried to work with routing ans search azure webapi commands. But no idea.